# "cordova-plugin-zip" was working on Android 8 but not in Android 12, 13

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

I had this funcion based on cordova (cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0) to unzip a .zip file working perfectly fine in Android 8:

```js
export async function decompressService() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
         window.zip.unzip(
             decompressionFileData.destinationURI, 
             decompressionFileData.destinationURIFolder, 
             (status) => {
                 if (status === 0) {
                     // Successfully unziped
                     const deletionCompressedFileData = {
                         destinationURIFolder: decompressionFileData.destinationURIFolder,
                         destinationURIFile: decompressionFileData.destinationURIFile
                     };
                     resolve(deletionCompressedFileData);
                 } else {
                     // There was an error, returning null
                     resolve(null);
                 }
             },
             (progress) => {
                 let percentage = Math.round((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100);
                 console.log(percentage);
             }
         );
     });
}
```

But now I updated a lot of things:

-Cordova is version 12 now

-Gradle v8.3

-Java v11

-Android platform v12 and v13 (API's 32 and 33 I think)

-The versions of the cordova plugins

And now everything keeps working fine EXCEPT FOR THIS FUNCTION (now always returns status -1). It also does not ask to user to enable permissions.

I think I saw something about a new way to handle READ and WRITE permissions for images and videos for newer versions of Android but Im not sure how to apply it in my case (handling zip files)
How can I solve this issue?

Note: I also have this plugins in my project (all of them seems to be working fine until now):

cordova-clipboard 1.3.0

cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.9

cordova-plugin-camera-preview 0.12.3

cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 5.0.2

cordova-plugin-device 2.1.0

cordova-plugin-file-transfer 2.0.0

cordova-plugin-file 8.0.0

cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0

cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5

cordova-sqlite-ext 6.0.0

cordova.plugins.diagnostic 7.1.2

JIC, I only use Cordova, not Ionic

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem after updating to Android 13. Did you find a solution?